# git-upload-pack command not found on windows

Tags: git, npm, github-pages

Hello everyone I'm trying to follow https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f to deploy a basic react page to github pages and I'm running into this issue when I run `npm run deploy`

```
git-upload-pack '.': git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

and when I do

```
which  git-upload-pack
```

I get an empty response. I've ensured that I do have access to this repo and the ssh keys are configured in a way that gives me access. This is a windows environment and I'm not finding too much information as to what I need to install to get git-upload-pack accessible.

Comment: Did you install Git for Windows?

Comment: Yup, I can run git commands.

Comment: `git upload-pack` is recognized for me, but `git-upload-pack` is not.

Comment: Quite recently, Git has started dropping most of the hyphenated spellings (`git-this-that`) for the standardized spellings used for the last 12 or so years (`git this-that`). Unfortunately `git-upload-pack` got missed at some point so a bunch of Git versions try to use the old hyphenated spelling when one of the newer Git installs doesn't install it. This has been corrected in an even-newer-Git (i.e., the old `git-upload-pack` spelling is now still installed, probably for the next 12 years). That's the background, not the solution, though.

Comment: The "canned" solution to the problem is to make sure that your Git versions are sufficiently synchronized on client and server. This means upgrading or downgrading client, server, or both until the two match. It's annoying and slightly painful. If you have direct access to the server, though, a simple fix is to make a `git-upload-pack` runnable program that either is, or runs, `git upload-pack`.

Comment: Ahh I'll have to check which version I have installed, that might be it. Thanks.